# UML - join after decision?

Tags: uml

Which one of those two is correct? Or maybe they should be merged by rhomb.

[image: First one]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The second is definitely wrong. A `Fork/Join` splits/gathers tokens that travel independently. Since there's only one token on the way the `Join` will never receive a second token to continue and hang permanently.

The first one is fine that way. You might alternatively use a `MergeNode` (same shape as the `DecisionNode` you use) to join the `ControlFlows` or join them outside the `Action`.

[image] or [image]